# Passing down router params to deep nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Taking on example from the `redux` [docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router#componentsapp.js) on how to use it with `react-router`:

```
const App = ({ match: { params } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AddTodo />
      <VisibleTodoList filter={params.filter || 'SHOW_ALL'} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Assuming both `redux` and `react-router` are correctly setup, how would you pass router params to a deeply nested component, say 3 levels down `VisibleTodoList`? Is there another way other than passing it on every single component starting from `App` -> `VisibleTodoList` -> `NestedOne` -> `...`?

Comment: Since I'm using `react-router-redux`, my first guess would be to listen to `LOCATION_CHANGE` action and add `filter` to the state. This way I could use a container in nested component, grab the filter from the state and pass it to the presentational component. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use withRouter() from react-router. It will inject router params. Example of VisibleTodoList.jsx:

```
import { withRouter } from `react-router`;
const VisibleTotoList = ({ match: { params } }) => { ... }
export default withRouter(VisibleTotoList);
```

Docs here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter